# Why is anaconda attempting to create new environments within existing ones, and how do I stop this behavior?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I'm creating a new anaconda env for a new project, however instead of the expected path (something like `C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\newEnv`) the package plan specifies that the environment location will be `C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\test1\envs\newEnv`.

From the base environment, I ran `conda create -n newEnv`, and got the following output:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 23.7.4
  latest version: 24.1.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda

Or to minimize the number of packages updated during conda update use

     conda install conda=24.1.0



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\test1\envs\newEnv



Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Why is it trying to create newEnv inside an existing environment I made for testing purposes?

Is this what I'm seeing, or have I misunderstood something?

I'd rather avoid having to use --prefix just to get conda to create an environment in the place environments are supposed to exist, and I'm mostly just curious why it's even trying to do it like this?